# Как взять данные о видео из вк?

Tags: javascript, php, html, vkontakte-api, youtube

Дело заключается в том, что я беру данные из пабликов и там иногда проскакивают данные о видео с вк или youtube'a. Этими данными являются `track_code`, `access_key` и т.д.

Как можно с помощью этих данных взять прямую ссылку на видео в вк или youtube, а после встроить ее на сайт для просмотра видео?

Answer (score 1):

Если группа с которой ты берешь видео закрытая, то для того чтобы получить к ней доступ нужно использовать access_key. К примеру в методе video.get

```
https://api.vk.com/method/video.get?videos=owner_id + _ + id + _ + access_key

https://api.vk.com/method/video.get?
access_token=access_token...&v=5.103&videos=-166884737_456251173_access_key
```

[image: some.jpg]

Comment: Извините, а где вы взяли этот скриншот?

Comment: @0xdb https://vk.com/dev/video.get

Comment: @Vadim Вы автор ответа и потерялуи свою уч. запись?

Comment: @0xdb мы -- нет